# How to add additional class name to an element?

Tags: javascript

I can't believe I can't find this in google - I need to add an additional class name to a `div` with the classname `checkField`:

```
<div id="wth" class="checkField"><label>Ok whatever</label></div>

document.getElementById("wth").className="error"; // This works
document.getElementsByClassName("field").className="error"; // Doesn't work
```

I tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("field").getElementsByTagName("label").className="error";
```

^ Also doesn't work.

Can someone please give me some advice? I'm too use to JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns a nodeList, which is an array-like object, not a single element. To do what you want you need to iterate the list:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("checkField");
if (divs) {
  // Run in reverse because we're
  // modifying the result as we go:
  for (var i=divs.length; i-- >= 0;) {
    divs[i].className = 'error';
  }
}
```

Also, just setting `className` actually replaces the class instead of adding to it. If you want to add another class you need to do it like this:

```
divs[i].className += ' error'; // notice the space bar
```

As for the second thing you're trying to do, that is setting the class of the label instead of the div, you need to loop through the divs and call `getElementsByTagName` on them:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("checkField");
if (divs) {
  // Run in reverse because we're
  // modifying the result as we go:
  for (var i=divs.length; i-- >= 0;) {
    var labels = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('label');
    if (labels) {
      for (var j=0; j<labels.length; j++) {
        labels[j].className = 'error';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Given that `.getElementsByClassName()` is supposed to return a _live_ NodeList, if you replace the class name as in your first example the loop won't work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/bhAsE/ - though it works if you loop backwards through the list. Of course this isn't an issue if you're adding a second class rather than replacing.

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) returns an [HTMLCollection](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection), which has a bit more functionality than a plain [NodeList](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the class onto the current value:

```
document.body.className += " foo"; // adds foo class to body
```

Some browsers support [`classList`](http://caniuse.com/classlist) which provides methods for adding, removing, and toggling classes on elements. For instance, you could add a new class like this:

```
document.body.classList.add("newClass");
```

Imagine the work involved in toggling a class; you'd have to perform some string operation to first determine whether a class is already on the element or not, and then respond accordingly. With `classList` you can just use the `toggle` method:

```
document.body.classList.toggle("toggleMe");
```

Some browsers don't currently support `classList`, but this won't prevent you from taking advantage of it. You can [download a polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) to add this feature where it's not natively supported.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

you want to do this by document.body

so try

```
var demo =document.body; 

// also do this by class like var demo = document.getElementsByClassName("div1one"); 
// or id var demo = document.getElementsId("div1one"); 

demo .className = demo .className + " otherclass";
```

or simpler solution if you have jquery as an option

```
 $("body").addClass("yourClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's are simple utility functions for adding and removing a class:

```
function addClass(elem, cls) {
    var oldCls = elem.className;
    if (oldCls) {
        oldCls += " ";
    }
    elem.className = oldCls + cls;
}

function removeClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    elem.className = str.replace(" " + cls + " ", " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}
```